# Defining python class method with multiple function signature

Tags: python, class

How to allow multiple behaviour of the delta_ method within the class depending on the parameters list?

```
class Greeks:

    @staticmethod
    def delta_(
        X: Option
    ) -> float:
        """
        Compute the delta of an option represented by an `Option` object.
        The delta measures the rate of change of the theoretical option value 
        with respect to changes in the underlying asset’s price.

        Parameters:
        X (Option): An `Option` object representing an option contract.

        Returns:
        float: The delta of the option.
        """
        if X.flag == 'c':
            return stats.norm.cdf(X.d1, 0, 1)
        elif X.flag == 'p':
            return -stats.norm.cdf(X.d1, 0, 1)
    
    @staticmethod
    def delta_(
        S: float,
        K: float,
        v: float,
        r: float,
        T: datetime.datetime,
        flag: str
    ) -> float:
        """
        Compute the delta of an option represented by its parameters.
        The delta measures the rate of change of the theoretical option value 
        with respect to changes in the underlying asset’s price.

        Parameters:
        S (float): The underlying asset price.
        K (float): The strike price.
        v (float): The volatility.
        r (float): The risk-free interest rate.
        T (datetime.datetime): The expiration date.
        flag (str): The option type ('c' for call, 'p' for put).

        Returns:
        float: The delta of the option.
        """
        T0 = datetime.datetime.today()
        t = ((T - T0).days + 1) / 365 # Time to expiration in years
        d1 = (np.log(S / K) + (r + 0.5 * v ** 2) * t) / (v * np.sqrt(t))
        if flag == 'c':
            return stats.norm.cdf(d1, 0, 1)
        elif flag == 'p':
            return -stats.norm.cdf(d1, 0, 1)
```

A possible solution, maybe not the cleanest, which allows one input only (Union[Option, Tuple[float, float, float, float, datetime.datetime, str]]) and has potentally lots of isinstance controls within:

```
class Greeks(object):

    @staticmethod
    def delta_(
        X: typing.Union[Option, typing.Tuple[float, float, float, float, datetime.datetime, str]]
    ) -> float:
        """
        Delta measures the rate of change of the theoretical option value 
        with respect to changes in the underlying asset’s price. 
        """
        if isinstance(X, Option):
            if X.flag == 'c': return stats.norm.cdf(X.d1, 0, 1)
            elif X.flag == 'p': return -stats.norm.cdf(X.d1, 0, 1)    
        else:
            S, K, v, r, T, flag = X
            T0 = datetime.datetime.today()
            t = ((T - T0).days + 1) / 365 # Time to expiration in years
            d1 = (np.log(S / K) + (r + 0.5 * v ** 2) * t) / (v * np.sqrt(t))
            d2 = d1 - v * np.sqrt(t)
            if flag == 'c': return stats.norm.cdf(d1, 0, 1)
            elif flag == 'p': return -stats.norm.cdf(d1, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Python itself doesn't care much about the type annotations. The only  thing similar to your request provided by the standard library is  [functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html?highlight=functools#functools.singledispatch). Otherwise you have to create a dispatcher function (or find an implementation) which detects the argument types and calls the appropriate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the @overload decorator to provide overloading.

Here is an example from the docs:

```
@overload
def process(response: None) -> None:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: int) -> tuple[int, str]:
    ...
@overload
def process(response: bytes) -> str:
    ...
def process(response):
    <actual implementation>
```

This only works after Python 3.5 or so.